# How to get values of a particular attribute in category page in Magento 2

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.3.0

I am using Magento 2.3

I want to display values of a particular attribute in category page.
For ex. I have an attribute called 'test' and I have 10 values in this attribute. I have selected different values of this attribute in different products.

Now I want to display values of "test" attribute which are selected in product(not all values) and I want to display list of attribute values in category page instead of product listing.

So How can I achieve this?

Comment: looks like you could improve your question: I understand your attribute is a product attribute that is multiselect? Also, it is not clear whether your attribute's selected values are different for a same product but in a different category? As it stands you use the word test too many times and I wonder if this helps us to understand your question or us to be lost with it..

Comment: you are right my question is complex and because of that I am not able to describe it clearly. So I will try to improve it

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar. I had an multi-select attribute named `availability` with possible options `Collect At Store` and `Home Delivery`. On listing page I had to show icons of these values were assigned for any particular product.

This is how I got it working in `list.phtml`

Inside `<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>` I have added following code:

```
<?php

if ($_product && ($attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('availability')) && $attr->usesSource())
    {
    if ($ids = explode(',', $_product->getData('availability')))
        {
        if (!empty($ids))
            {
            foreach($ids as $id)
                {
                $deliveryOption = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($id); ?>
                            <?php
                if ($deliveryOption == 'Collect At Store')
                    { ?> 
                                <!-- show Collect At Store icon -->
                            <?php
                    } ?>
                             <?php
                if ($deliveryOption == 'Home Delivery')
                    { ?> 
                                <!-- show Collect At Store icon -->
                            <?php
                    } ?>

                        <?php
                }
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

You can follow this example to show your attribute values.

Answer (score 1):

To display the attribute value in product list page, add the below code in app/design/frontend/YOUR_VENDOR/YOUR_THEME/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

```
<?php echo$_item->getTest(); ?>
```